# JSoup - How to extract only the href in paragraph

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following:

```html
</div>
  <p>
    <a href="https://urlIwant.com" data-wpel-link="internal">
      <span class="image-holder" style="padding-bottom:149.92679355783%;">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://urlIwant.com" width="683" height="1024" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-200816" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span id="more-20000"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://urlIwant.com" data-wpel-link="internal">
      <span class="image-holder" style="padding-bottom:149.92679355783%;">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://urlIwant.com" width="683" height="1024" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-200833" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://urlIwant.com" data-wpel-link="internal">
      <span class="image-holder" style="padding-bottom:145.71428571429%;">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://urlIwant.com" width="700" height="1020" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-200834" sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, 700px" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://urlIwant.com" data-wpel-link="internal">
      <span class="image-holder" style="padding-bottom:143.42857142857%;">
        <img loading="lazy" src="https://urlIwant.com" width="700" height="1004" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-200835" 836w" sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, 700px" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

How can I extract all of the urls that contain the `paragraph` tag, `href` and contains the `class` `"image-holder"`?

I can't figure out how to add the span class

```java
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://urltoextractfrom.com").get();
    Elements selections = doc.select("p a[href]");
    for (Element e : selections) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your HTML sample is faulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood what you want to extract correctly, you can use this selector:

```
p a:has(span.image-holder)
```

That finds all the `a` elements which descend from a `p` element, and which contain a `span` with class `image-holder` set.

So in code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = document.select("p a:has(span.image-holder)");
List<String> urls = links.eachAttr("href");
```

You can use the try.jsoup REPL to quickly iterate on selectors.
[https://try.jsoup.org/~wvd2VHaJtnr10qEiLS9g_-E6UA8](https://try.jsoup.org/%7Ewvd2VHaJtnr10qEiLS9g_-E6UA8)

(If there's content this selects that you don't want to, you can clarify that in your question with examples.)

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a better answer please post it but I got this working after 3 hours of trying...

```
try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://urltoextractfrom.com").get();
            Elements selections = doc.select("p a[href]");
            for (Element e : selections) {
                Elements elements2 = e.select("span[class=image-holder]");
                if(elements2.attr("class").equals("image-holder")){
                    System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```